# Angularjs md-select not set placeholder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

Following code of `<md-select/>` not showing any placeholder even when i added a `placeholder="Select Type"`

```
<md-select ng-model="ctrl.number" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}" placeholder="Select Type">
    <md-option ng-repeat="n in ctrl.numbers" ng-value="n">
      {{ n.value }}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

But it will work with below code

```
  <md-select ng-model="ctrl.number"  placeholder="Select Type">
    <md-select-label>{{ ctrl.number.value }}</md-select-label>
    <md-option ng-repeat="n in ctrl.numbers" ng-value="n">{{ n.value }}</md-option>
  </md-select>
```

**JS Code**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular
      .module('MyApp')
      .controller('AppCtrl', function() {
        var _this = this;

        _this.number = {id: 2, value: "Two"};
        _this.numbers = [
          {id: 0, value: "Zero"},
          {id: 1, value: "One"},
          {id: 2, value: "Two"},
          {id: 3, value: "Three"},
          {id: 4, value: "Four"},
          {id: 5, value: "Five"}
        ];
      });
})();
```

Can someone please let me know what is wrong with first  and how to set `placeholder` in that case ?

Comment: i think when you add `ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}"` it will pre select an item in the options. so placeholder will removed

Comment: @sachilaranawaka its not possible both should work? When on select of item i have to perform operation and only one option loaded from db then it is causing issue.

Comment: can you create a demo of it .?

Comment: How can you expect it to show placeholder if you are setting a model ctrl.number already and that model exists in option also

Comment: @SubodhJoshi see this http://plnkr.co/edit/5v4ZtIimJA7VtWFqoJIV?p=preview

Comment: @Viplock I have created a demo but not sure how to add angular their https://jsfiddle.net/Subodh_Joshi/x4ku569x/

Comment: @SubodhJoshi this is your update jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j2621jt1/1/ now elaborate the problem

Comment: @Viplock Thanks for your update

Comment: Same thing with `this` https://jsfiddle.net/5mdgct4z/

Comment: @Viplock Yes you are right placeholder not working in second and third example

Comment: its not like , place holder is not working . its about value is selected so place holder not needed. here you need a label beside the select. Coz you use place holder to tell about the input provider and if it will have a default value, you need a label.

Answer (score -1):

```
<md-select ng-model="ctrl.number" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}" 
placeholder="Select Type">
<md-option value="">Select Type</md-option>
<md-option ng-repeat="n in ctrl.numbers" ng-value="n">
  {{ n.value }}
</md-option>`
</md-select>
```

Your code works fine. Placeholder displays when not selected. You should add "md-option value="" to unselect.

Comment: This suggestion creates a selectable option in the list which is not necessary when using a placeholder.